# Can we express the electrodynamic potentials $V$, $\mathbf{A}$ in terms of the electrodynamic fields $\mathbf{E}$, $\mathbf{B}$?

Tags: electromagnetism, gauge-theory, gauge

In Griffiths' *Introduction to Electrodynamics* problem 10.25, I am asked to draw a "triangle diagram" illustrating the relationship between (1) the sources $\rho$, $\mathbf{J}$, (2) the fields $\mathbf{E}$, $\mathbf{B}$, and (3) the potentials $V$, $\mathbf{A}$. However, the question explicitly leaves out the arrow that expresses the potentials in terms of the fields.

The answer key given is
[image]

In the electro/magnetostatic cases, such a relationship can be separately given as
$$ V(\mathbf{r}) = \int_\mathcal{O}^\mathbf{r}\mathrm{d}\mathbf{l}'\cdot\mathbf{E}$$
or
$$ V(\mathbf{r}) = \frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\int\mathrm{d}\tau'\text{ }\mathbf{E}\cdot\frac{\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}'}{|\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}'|^3}, $$
and
$$ \mathbf{A}(\mathbf{r}) = \frac{1}{4\pi}\int\mathrm{d}\tau'\text{ }\mathbf{B}\times\frac{\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}'}{|\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}'|^3}. $$

But I do not know how to incorporate time-dependence into this relationship. So my question is, is there a way to express the electrodynamic potentials in terms of the electrodynamic fields?

Comment: In which gauge?

Comment: I have done one in the Lorentz gauge below.

Comment: @Qmechanic I would guess since we are dealing with electrodynamics, the Lorenz gauge would make it less messy, but what do I know...

Comment: Technically, one might use any gauge one wishes, so that any attempt to derive a potential is non-unique.

Answer (score 1):

Just about the only way to do it is like you have done it there, i.e. writing the scalar and vectorpotentials in terms of the integral quantities. However, the one's you have written do not take into account the time dependence, as you so note in your post. The way to account for the electrodynamic aspect is similar, namely you must use the expressions for the "retarded potentials" in combination with Maxwell's equations.
Thus, one has:
$$\phi(\vec r,t)={1\over 4\pi\epsilon_0}\int{\rho(\vec r^\prime,t^\prime)\over |\vec 
r-\vec r^\prime|}\;dV^\prime, $$
$$\vec A(\vec r,t)={\mu_0\over 4\pi}\int {\vec J(\vec r^\prime,t^\prime)\over |\vec r-\vec r^\prime|}\; dV^\prime.$$
Where $t^\prime$ is the retarded time:
$$t^\prime=t-{|\vec r-\vec r^\prime|\over c}.$$
Now use Maxwell's equations:
$$\nabla\cdot \vec D=\rho;\;\; \nabla\times\vec H-{\partial\vec D\over\partial t}=\vec J,$$ to eleminate the sources in favor of the fields.
Now, this scheme is perhaps of use to someone in pursuit of knowledge for knowledge's sake, however, the reason Griffiths failed to draw the arrow as you mentioned, is because there is basically no use for writing the potentials in terms of the fields. The sole use of the potentials is to perform calculations that in some way or the other provide us information concerning the fields, not the other way around.

Comment: I don't think the question by the OP is just of an academic nature. Such 'inverse problems' are quite common in physics (and other areas of science) where you try to derive the internal structure of objects from whatever information is available outside. In this case, it seems quite a reasonable undertaking trying to derive the structure and motion of a charge distribution from the observed electromagnetic fields.

Comment: I didn't know they were quite common, thanks for this input, it would seem to me that if one knew the fields, the motion and structure of charge distributions could be ascertained from the Maxwell equations without recourse to the potentials.

Comment: The Wikipedia article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_problem gives a good overview over 'inverse problems' in general. These can be mathematically quite difficult to solve though, and you need obviousluy a sufficient number of data as input. On my web page https://www.plasmaphysics.org.uk/retrieval.htm I have described a working solution of the Inverse Radiative Transfer Problem